# my form doesen't work right

Tags: html, forms

I made a form but it doesn't send to my email; instead, it opens Windows Live Mail.

Here is my code:

`<form name="name" action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post">`

What can I do to make the form send to my email instead of opening Windows Live Mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code IS good. Your code does exactly what it is supposed to do. When you submit a form with  `action` attribute involving a `mailto:`, it opens up your email program to send an email to the `someone@example.com` address.

If you want the form to not send the email using the system's default mail program, you need to use something server-side. I don't know of any client side solutions, but who knows. There might be something out there...

Comment: but it opens my mail it have to send one

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give more details?

Comment: when I press send I get an alert that the form is sending by e-mail.

Comment: so I press ok en my e-mail progam opens

Comment: You have to press the "send" button.

Comment: I do that, it just won't send

Comment: @DuncanSterken This sounds like a problem with how Windows Live Mail is configured, not with your code.